# a Scroll button on chrome IOS doesn't hide the address bar

Tags: ios, google-chrome, scroll

Obviously when scrolling on chrome under iOS the address bar disappears.

Have a website where the the front page have a button which scrolls to the next section, i would really like that button to behave as if the user actually scroll the page, therefore, hiding the address bar.

how can i achieve that ?